# PostgreSQL (shp2pgsql) AddGeometryColumn gives "No function matches the given name"

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm working with the [PADUS OBI shape file](http://www.databasin.org/protected-center/features/PAD-US-CBI/download), not that that's probably important.

I'm running the shape file through shp2pgsql using the default options, as in:

```
shp2pgsql PADUS_1_1_CBI_Edition.shp > PADUS.sql
```

Then I'm trying to import the SQL into Postgres by doing:

```
psql -d padusdb -f PADUS.sql
```

And getting the following error:

```
psql:PADUS.sql:36: ERROR:  function addgeometrycolumn(unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT AddGeometryColumn('','padus_1_1_cbi_edition','the_geo...
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I have PostGIS installed.

The SQL commands leading to the error (being put into an otherwise empty database) are:

```
SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO UTF8;
SET STANDARD_CONFORMING_STRINGS TO ON;
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "padus_1_1_cbi_edition" (gid serial PRIMARY KEY,
"us_id" int4,
"category" varchar(10),
"gis_acres" numeric,
...
BUNCH OF COLUMNS, none of which is called "the_geom"
...
"comments" varchar(200),
"shape_leng" numeric,
"shape_area" numeric);
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('','padus_1_1_cbi_edition','the_geom','-1','MULTIPOLYGON',2);
COMMIT;
```

Any thoughts on what this might mean and how to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, as it turns out, it is not enough to simply have installed PostGIS on one's machine.

Originally, I'd chosen `sudo apt-get install postgresql postgis` on Ubuntu 10.10. This left me with a working version of PostGRE 8.4, but no sign of PostGIS.

Therefore, I tried `sudo apt-get install postgresql-8.4-postgis`.

But one's work doesn't end there! You need to set up the PostGIS database.

[This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#creating-a-spatial-database-template-for-postgis) website provides instructions on doing this and using the database afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

It also sounds like the database needs to be spatially enabled. The reason it's throwing that errors is because the function is missing. This [resource](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiNewbieAddgeometrycolumn) has a quick and easy answer and solution.

Answer (score 0):

this error indicates that the function cannot be recognized (either function name or parameters types are incorrect)

this is the [definitions for AddGeometryColumn](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html) in v7.2

```
text AddGeometryColumn(varchar table_name, varchar column_name, integer srid, varchar type, integer dimension);

text AddGeometryColumn(varchar schema_name, varchar table_name, varchar column_name, integer srid, varchar type, integer dimension);

text AddGeometryColumn(varchar catalog_name, varchar schema_name, varchar table_name, varchar column_name, integer srid, varchar type, integer dimension);
```

it looks to me like you're trying to use the 2nd definition, try changing it to use the first definition (no schema) and try unquote the srid (-1) since it should be passed as an integer.

You may need to cast everything...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks atorres757!  Your answer solved my problem in minutes.  I deleted my database and created a new database and choose the template_postgis as my template.  All shapefiles are importing fine with my python script like this:

> for lyr in iList:
>
> > os.system("shp2pgsql -c -s 4326 -k -I -W UTF-8 "+lyr[:-4]+" "+lyr[:-4]+" | psql -d AWM -p 5432 -U postgres")